# Where can I see Asterisk REST recordings listing?

Tags: json, rest, asterisk

I have recently installed FreeBPX with asterisk included. I activated the rest interface, so I can see [/ari/asterisk/info](http:///ari/asterisk/info) and it responds with a JSON. Now I want to see all my call recordings. I configured recordings and the server saves them in wav format. It's ok, but how can I see them through json/rest? I tried open [/ari/asterisk/recordings](http:///ari/asterisk/recordings), but it responds with "resource not found".

Answer (score 0):

As yo can see in the [docs](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+12+Recordings+REST+API), you can use:

```
GET /recordings/stored/{recordingName}
```

EDIT: You can see the list of recordings stored with

```
GET /recording/stored
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please tell me where can i get recording name?

Comment: i tried /ari/recordings/stored/in-10168201-79068001145-20150616-101350-1434431630.5235.wav without success

Comment: Please, post the response for the list of recordings

Comment: {
message: "Recording not found"
}

Comment: This is for the entire list, or for a single recording?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the point here, the ARI recordings interface isn't meant to be used with the files that you have stored via FreePBX. The recordings API is meant to allow you to manage recordings, from within a Stasis application. That means, start a recording from a Stasis application and manage it. If the recording had been performed outside of Stasis, the ARI engine will not be aware of it.

Well, at least that's what it's supposed to do.

Nir

Answer (score 0):

This is partly doable - FreePBX doesn't seem to use the native Asterisk recording APIs so you can only retrieve the filename

First get all the channels:

```
GET /ari/channels
```

Find your channel's ID from the response's `id` field
Then you can request the variable `CALLFILENAME` from the channel's variable endpoint:

```
GET /ari/channels/{id}/variable?variable=CALLFILENAME
```